# jQuery animate image increase width and height from center of screen

Tags: jquery, animation

I have an image of a hollow circle. I need 10 of these circles to increase from 0px width and height to 1000px width and height from the center of the screen. The animations need to start at different intervals to each other so you get expanding concentric circles and the images opacity needs to change to 0. Below is the code I currently have, however it is pretty jerky and not ideal. Is there anything that I am doing wrong here?

```
<style type="text/css">
    body{background-color:black;padding:0px;margin:0px;height:100%;width:100%;position:relative;}
    .newsCircle{position:absolute;padding:10px;}
    #animationNews{width:100%;height:100%;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var numNewsCircles = 4;
    var $animationNews;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $animationNews = $("#animationNews");

        var animationNewsTop = ($(window).height() - 20) / 2;
        var animationNewsLeft = ($(window).width() - 20) / 2;
        for (var i = 1; i <= numNewsCircles; i++) {
            $animationNews.append($('<img class="newsCircle" style="width:0px;height:0px;top:' + animationNewsTop + 'px;left:' + animationNewsLeft + 'px" id="newsCircle' + i + '" src="images/animations/news.gif" />'));
        }
        animateNews();
    });

    function animateNews() {
        var newLeft = ($(window).width() - 1020) / 2;
        var newTop = ($(window).height() - 1020) / 2;
        for (var i = 1; i <= numNewsCircles; i++) {
            var delay = 2000 * i;
            $("#newsCircle" + i).delay(delay).animate({ height: 1000 + "px", width: 1000 + 'px', left: newLeft + 'px', top: newTop + 'px' }, 3000, function () {

            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Any help on this is really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I for one would also be curious to see if anyone has a CSS3 transforms version!